# How to use a select query results in an update query?

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables:
`films(id,marksNum)`
`marks(id,film_id,mark)`
I'd like to save number of marks for each film in `films.marksNum`.
My attempt is:

```
UPDATE films
SET marksNum=
(
SELECT  count(id)
FROM marks
WHERE marks.film_id=films.id
GROUP BY marks.film_id
)
WHERE films.id=marks.film_id
```

but I'v got an error: `no such column: marks.film_id`
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why even do that? Do you have performance issues? If not then don't store redundant data

Comment: @juergend I don't want to count it each time I need the number.

Comment: @Vlad Then you should create a trigger on the `marks` table which will increment the count every time a new mark gets added.

Comment: But that is how you should do it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for the idea! But I guess the trigger will not help to count the current number of marks?

Comment: No...my idea is to somehow maintain the count always in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not an elegan solve but any way:
1)

```
CREATE TABLE `grp_marks` ( `film_id` INTEGER, `marks_num` INTEGER )
```

2)

```
INSERT INTO grp_marks(film_id,marks_num)
SELECT film_id,count(id)
FROM marks
GROUP BY film_id
```

3)

```
UPDATE films
SET marksNum=
(
SELECT marks_num
FROM grp_marks
WHERE (film_id=films.id)
)
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM grp_marks WHERE grp_marks.film_id=films.id
)
```